# How can I pivot my T-SQL query output to get this specific table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am running a `T-SQL` query on `SQL Server 2014`. The query and its output are given below:

```
Use MyDatabase
   SELECT 
   ID,
   ArrivalMonth,
   DateOfBirth
   FROM [View1]
   WHERE [ArrivalMonth] between '2017-01-01' and '2018-05-01'
```

The output of the above query looks like this (extract):

```
 ID    ArrivalMonth     DateOfBirth
 101   2017-01-01       1974-05-30
 105   2017-05-01       1967-03-05
 125   2017-05-01       NULL
 ...   ...              ...
```

I need a `T-SQL` query to give me the following output (based on the output above):

```
 ArrivalMonth   Number_Of_Bookings    Number_Of_DOB_Captured
 2017-01-01         130                 110
 2017-02-01          90                  85
 ...                ...                 ...
 2018-05-01         115                  70
```

The first column is the `ArrivalMonth`. `Number_Of_Bookings` is the count of number of records from the above query. `Number_Of_DOB_Captured` is the count of `DateOfBirth` which is `NOT NULL`.

I think may be the `Pivot` query might be the solution but I am confused as to how to execute it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may left join a calendar table containing all the months to your current table, and then aggregate:

```
WITH months AS (
    SELECT '2017-01-01' AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-02-01' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2017-12-01'
)

SELECT
    m.month,
    COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Bookings,
    COUNT(v.DateOfBirth) AS Number_Of_DOB_Captured
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN [View1] v
    ON m.month = v.ArrivalMonth
WHERE
    v.ArrivalMonth BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-05-01'
GROUP BY
    m.month;
```

The calendar table may be necessary here if it could be possible that, for some reason, a given arrival month have no data associated with it in your view.  If you are certain that the view would always contain data for every month, then you may aggregate directly on your table without joining.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `count(Number_Of_Bookings)`, `count(DateOfBirth)` and `group by ArrivalMonth`

So you count the number of non null values for each different `ArrivalMonth`.

the query :

```
Select ArrivalMonth
     , count(Number_Of_Bookings)
     , count(DateOfBirth)
 FROM [View1]
WHERE [ArrivalMonth] between '2017-01-01' and '2018-05-01'
group by ArrivalMonth
```